# My autocomplete suggestion list takes much time to appear and it freezes the keyboard?

Tags: c#, xamarin

In Ui, I am suggesting a list if anyone enters any character by filtering it from a list. I am using `listview.itemsource`. It takes much time to appear and the keyboard gets frozen until the list appears.

I am filtering a list based on the character entered and storing it in `listview.itemsource`. the filtered list takes much time to appear on the UI side and till then my keyboard stays frozen, not able to enter the next character.

```
    list2 = list.Where(x => x.CardHolderName.Trim().ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
      
    FilteredPersonList = ConvertListToObservableCollection(list2);
                            if (FilteredPersonList != null && FilteredPersonList.Count > 0)
                            {
                                this.listView.IsVisible = true;
                                this.searchBarStack.HeightRequest = 250;
                                this.listView.ItemsSource = FilteredPersonList;
                            }
```

here `listView` is a variable that denotes `ListView`.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the code below which shows a SearchBar query with results displayed in a ListView. It would not take much time to appear and it does not freeze the keyboard.

Xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar x:Name="_searchbar" Placeholder="Search..." TextChanged="_searchbar_TextChanged"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code:

```
 public partial class Page22 : ContentPage
{
    public List<ListViewItem> Items { get; set; }
    public Page22()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<ListViewItem>
    {
          new ListViewItem { Name = "AAAA" },
          new ListViewItem { Name = "ABBB" },
          new ListViewItem { Name = "AAAA" },
          new ListViewItem { Name = "CCCC" },
          new ListViewItem { Name = "DAAB" },
          new ListViewItem { Name = "DDDC" }
    };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void _searchbar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        list.ItemsSource = FilterItem(e.NewTextValue);
    }
    IEnumerable<ListViewItem> FilterItem(string filter = null)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            return Items;
        return Items.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(filter));
    }
}
public class ListViewItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```